# How to use drawInRect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've started a absolutely new XCode project for iPhone apps and put just the following code in viewDidLoad.(No Frameworks added or imported, no other Code)
I'm using iOS 7.
Nothing happens. It should write "Hello" to the screen. What did I do wrong?

```
[@"Hello" drawInRect:rect withAttributes:[NSDictionary
                                                      dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                      nil]];
```

Comment: You're going to have to learn a bunch more it seems...go read some docs. drawInRect draws to the current context, not the screen. This code will work if put into the DrawRect: function, assuming the codes itself works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code for drawing text, but that's not how you generally add text to the screen in iOS. In iOS, the model for adding text to the screen generally consists of just adding a `UILabel` to the view controller's view, for example, in `viewDidLoad`, you could do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    // or, if you really wanted to use an attributed string:
    //
    // UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    // NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"
    //                                                                        attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
    //                                                                                     NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]}];
    // [label setAttributedText:attributedString];
    // [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Where you need this `drawInRect` method is when you're drawing within a special context, e.g. in a `UIView` subclass. So, you might define a `UIView` subclass and write a `drawRect` method that uses your code:

For example, CustomView.h:

```
//  CustomView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView

@end
```

And CustomView.m:

```
//  CustomView.m

#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [@"Hello" drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                                               NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]}];
}

@end
```

You can then add a `CustomView` in your view controller:

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}

@end
```

As you can tell, that's a little cumbersome, fine for very particular situations, but on the basis of what you shared with us, it's far more cumbersome than you probably need to consider. Generally you wouldn't use the `drawInRect` method if you just wanted to add text to your view in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect works. I'm trying to find the best way to resize a text in an UIView like a Label or Button, after the Buttons size gets changed. It should fit the new size.

Comment: @user2415476 You either change the `CGRect` that you use, or increasingly nowadays people would use auto layout (iOS 6+) to control the relative placement of separate controls.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible to use directly the **drawInRect:** method of NSAttributedString:

```
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:self.displayAttributes];
    CGContextSaveGState(cgContext);
    [attributedString drawInRect:frame];
    CGContextRestoreGState(cgContext);
```